# call MS Power Automate from a TypeScript Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, power-automate

how can I trigger a MS Power Automate HTTPtrigger from a TypeScript Azure Function. Anyone? I've been trying this but without any luck.

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
    todo: 'Buy the milk'
  })
  
  const options = {
    hostname: flowUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
  }
  
  const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
  
    res.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
  })
  
  req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
  
  req.write(data)
  req.end()
```

Comment: Is there any error message ?

Comment: Yes, I get agetaddrinfo ENOTFOUND, even though I'm sure that the link to my Power Automate Httptrigger is correct

Comment: Hi Nicolai, it seems you can't just use one property `hostname` in `options`. Please refer to the solution I provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just use a `hostname` property in `options` but without `port` and `path` properties. We can't put the whole flow url in `hostname` of `options`, we need to separate it as `hostname`, `port` and `path`.

For example my flow url is `https://prod-06.eastasia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/e79330xxxxxxxxxxxcf029ac/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=mEAzy9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPqCwJBCc2mg`, then the code should be like:

```
const options = {
    hostname: "prod-06.eastasia.logic.azure.com",   //note: do not add "https://" here
    method: 'POST',
    port: '443',
    path: '/workflows/e79330xxxxxxxxxxxcf029ac/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=mEAzy9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPqCwJBCc2mg',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
}
```

After this change, the code can trigger the http trigger in my power automate.